# Не работает socket.io в модуле

Tags: сокет, node.js

Есть такой  server.js 
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

```
server.listen(8080);
var Stat = require('./app/models/stat');

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    Stat.find(function(err, stat) {

      if (err) return console.error(err);

      console.log(stat);


      var data1 = stat;

      io.sockets.emit('pushdata', data1);

});
```

если использовать io.on в файле server.js, то всё работает, если же пробовать вынести его в контроллер, то ни какой реакции